Can't use touchpad in Ubuntu 24.04 (ROG Zephyrus G15 )
The touchpad is not detected even in the ROG Zephyrus G15's BIOS, and there is no touchpad in cat /proc/bus/input/devices. I tried installing the FocalTech Touchpad driver and it also does not work. It works fine in Windows 11.
